# How to Write Trigger(on after insert) to Delete all Rows in Table Except Last Two Rows?

Tags: sql-server, linq, stored-procedures, triggers, linq-to-entities

I want a Sql Script Trigger on after insert, Which can Delete all Rows in table except Last Two Rows.
And I Want Similar Code in Entity linq too Please...
I know my question is cheap for you experts but i really do not know how to code it...
So help me please?

I Use This Code But Has error in syntax :

```
select * from TblGold where id not in (
select id from TblGold 
order by id desc 
limit 2
)
```

The Error Is :

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4 Incorrect syntax near 'limit'.
```

By the way, I know how to write a trigger but do not know how to Delete All Records Except 2 Last record.
And nither Linq Codes.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte
AS
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id DESC) AS RowNumber, *
FROM TblGold
)
DELETE TblGold
FROM
    TblGold T
    INNER JOIN cte ON cte.Id = T.Id
WHERE RowNumber > 2
```

Comment: Modified query. Be aware order in DB is not guaranteed, so your're forced to specify the column you want to order by. If you don't have this column you can create a calculated column where to store time stamp. Check this link: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188751(v=sql.105).aspx